# Etymology of "Shtiebel"

Tags: yiddish, etymology

Is there an etymological connection between the Yiddish word "shtiebel" and the English word "steeple"? They seem to overlap a lot in usage and pronunciation. A cursory search reveals that "shtiebel" may be a diminutive of the Yiddish word for "house", but perhaps the two derivations converged at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now guess this:
room in German is Stube. Diminutive: Stübchen or: in dialect: Stüble (little room).
The diminutive in Yiddish ususally ends in -lach. -ü- not existing in Yiddish, it is transformed into -i-.
So simply Stüblein becomes stiblach (pronoucenced shtiblakh) in Yiddish.

DHL

Comment: DHL, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for this convincing etymology! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking on register/login, above.

Comment: But Yiddish, though it's closely related to German, and though it doubtless borrowed a number of words from German, is not _descended_ from German. Do you have any particular reason to think that this word was borrowed from the German _Stube_, rather than that (as my answer suggests) it's cognate to (descended from an ancestor shared by) the German _Stube_?

Comment: Also: I believe _-lach_ or _-lech_ is the _plural_ diminutive suffix (with _-l_ being the singular). (_-lech_ or _-lich_ is also another suffix, forming adjectives, as in _mentschlech_, but that's another story.) This doesn't detract from the thrust of your answer at all, though, of course.

Answer (score 4):

The only meaning of "shtibl" that I know of is "a little house".   There is a song performed by the Barry sisters that begins: "In main shteitl shteit a shtibl mit a grinem dach..." - "In my village stands a little house with a green roof..."

The word for "house" in both the Galician and the southern (Ukrainian) dialects of Yiddish is "shtib".  It would be "shtub" in the Lithuanian dialect.  "Shtibl" is a diminutive of "shtib".

Comment: Right, but it's come to mean a small synagogue.

Comment: Really?  Not that I am an expert, but I have never heard of that meaning.  Could you be confusing it with "shil", which is the Ukrainian or Galician pronunciation of "shul"?

Comment: No. See also http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%91%D7%9C .

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to believe that the two are related. Though I recall hearing (in my youth) that the name of [Country Yossi](http://countryyossi.com/STAGE1/main.php?page=shop_home)'s "Shteeble Hoppers" album was a take-off on a Steeple-related band name.

[Update: I emailed CY, and he said the name "just sounded cute" and had nothing to do with steeples. So much for that myth!]

Comment: Another point: The German word for room is "stube," which is quite different from the word "steeple." It's not expected that the Yiddish pronunciation-shifts which converted "stube" into "shtieble" were duplicated in other languages.

Comment: Plus one for the extra email research.

Answer (score 2):

I'm **guessing** Yiddish *shtibl* is actually related to English [*stove*, which may be from Vulgar Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stove), whereas *steeple* is [apparently from a Germanic root and completely unrelated](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=steeple).

Comment: Cool! Why would shtiblach be named after bathrooms?

Comment: Well, steambaths, apparently. Perhaps because they get crowded and hot, and people wear thick talisos? :-) No, seriously, that root descended into German via Old High German 'stuba' which apparently referred to any heated room, so my guess is Yiddish 'shtub', "house", is also a descendant. (Yiddish is also from Old High German.) From there it's a short hop to 'shtibl'.

Answer (score 1):

Shtiebel is usually a Hassidic type synagogue, which was/is often in a house, as opposed to being a larger, free standing building, as is more common among non-Hassidic Shuls.

Perhaps it is that often the (Hassidic) Rebbe of the shtiebel lives in the same building, which he often owns, which is not usually the case in a standard Shul, where the Rav usually lives elsewhere and does not own the premises.